# Which one is better at keeping you warm?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

Does Glass feel warmer during winter when you keep your feet on it or Wood?

Comment: Have you experimented or searched on the web? The downvotes reflect the poor quality of your question. To improve it you should include some own experience, search results, or other relevant information you have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics

Comment: Here's a Veritasium video [Misconceptions About Temperature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqDbMEdLiCs) that may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materials at the same temperature "feel" differently warm because of their different heat conductivity. The higher the conductivity is, the faster the material drives the heat away from your skin, and the faster it moves the temperature of your skin towards the surrounding temperature (which is lower than your body temperature, at least in a typical winter situation).

Metals have the highest conductivity, so they feel coldest. Glass feels a bit warmer and wood, a heat insulator, feels even warmer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to @Lubos Motl's answer that when you put your feet on wood due to its low conductivity your feet makes the upper layer of the wood warmer whereas other part of wood remain at low temperature, whereas in the case of glass, or metals due to their larger conductivity, the heat given by your feet is conducted to larger part of the material and the corresponding temperature rise is low. Hence after a while wood start to feel little warmer.

This is the same principle as applied in warm cloths.

regards